# installing gputools on windows

Tags: r, windows, cuda, gpu

I am trying to install the R package gputools on a windows machine. According to the  [install instuctions](http://brainarray.mbni.med.umich.edu/brainarray/rgpgpu/install.txt)  there is no support for windows. The linux instructions however are all about instructing the r package where to find the cuda folder, so I'm thinking this should be possible on windows.

The config.mk file is

```
# set R_HOME, R_INC, and R_LIB to the the R install dir,
# the R header dir, and the R shared library dir on your system
R_HOME := $(shell R RHOME)
R_INC := $(R_HOME)/include
R_LIB := $(R_HOME)/lib

# replace these three lines with
# CUDA_HOME := <path to your cuda install>
ifndef CUDA_HOME
    CUDA_HOME := /usr/local/cuda
endif

# set CUDA_INC to CUDA header dir on your system
CUDA_INC := $(CUDA_HOME)/include

ARCH := $(shell uname -m)

# replace these five lines with
# CUDA_LIB := <path to your cuda shared libraries>
ifeq ($(ARCH), i386)
    CUDA_LIB := $(CUDA_HOME)/lib
else
    CUDA_LIB := $(CUDA_HOME)/lib64
endif

OS := $(shell uname -s)
ifeq ($(OS), Darwin)
    ifeq ($(ARCH), x86_64)
        DEVICEOPTS := -m64
    endif
    CUDA_LIB := $(CUDA_HOME)/lib
    R_FRAMEWORK := -F$(R_HOME)/.. -framework R
    RPATH := -rpath $(CUDA_LIB)
endif

CPICFLAGS := $(shell R CMD config CPICFLAGS)
```

I have modified the config.mk file by replacing every instance of `$(CUDA_HOME)` with `C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v6.5/lib` and `$(R_HOME)` with `C:/R/R-3.1.2`.

After this I rezipped the package folder and tried to install it with `install.packages("C:/Users/prg/Desktop/gputools_0.28.tar/gputools_0.28/gputools.zip", repos = NULL)` but this give the error `file ‘src/config.mk’ has the wrong MD5 checksum`.

Is there a way to get past the MD5 check? Do I need to specify anything else in the config.mk folder?

After following cdeterman's and RHertel's suggestion I rebuild the tar file with `R CMD build gputools_0.28` after deleting the MD5 file. Trying to install the package now no longer gives a checksum error, but a compilation error:

```
* installing *source* package 'gputools' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gputools'
* removing 'C:/Users/prg/Desktop/gputools/gputools_0.28/gputools.Rcheck/gputools'
```

I have installed Rtools and MinGw, any ideas on what I can do to get gputools  to compile?

Comment: "After this I rezipped the package folder" I believe you need to study [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html).

Comment: I had tried much before getting gputools. Please post an update if you manage to get this working.

Comment: Just delete the MD5 file?  Or at least the line within the file corresponding to the `src/config.mk` file.

Answer (score 4):

This could be the problem: "After this I rezipped the package". How did you do this? I've never tried it, but I assume that simply zipping the directory might not work. 
I suggest that you create the modified package with `R CMD build gputools_0.28`.

Comment: After following cdeterman's and RHertel's suggestion I rebuild the tar file with `R CMD build gputools_0.28` after deleting the MD5 file. Trying to install the package now no longer gives a checksum error, but a compilation error:



`* installing *source* package 'gputools' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gputools'
* removing 'C:/Users/prg/Desktop/gputools/gputools_0.28/gputools.Rcheck/gputools'`




I have installed Rtools and MinGw, any ideas on what I can do to get gputools to compile?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but I suspect that gputools may simply not work on Windows. CUDA requires Visual Studio in Windows, so you may need to perform the compilation there (MinGW might not help in this case). Sorry that I can't be more helpful. The only thing I can say is that it is easy to install on Linux. I noticed that even @Dirk Eddelbuettel wrote a [similar comment](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-hpc/2012-September/001503.html) a while ago.